# get input value in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I had 2 input value, I need to do validation on first `input` value which is credit card number input, get `input` value on ts file and check validation on API while user still typing on second `input`, example of my first input value: `4444 4444 4444 4444`, so i need to use `subString()` to get first 6 number before do validation, 
this is what I had tried;

**html file**

```
  <div>
    <input
      (keypress)="numberOnly($event)"
      class="input"
      type="text"
      (keyup)="onKey($event)"
      [(ngModel)]="creditCardNo"
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input
      class="input"
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="cardHolderName"
    />
  </div>
```

**ts file**

```
  onKey(event) {
    this.creditCardNo = event.target.value;
    const test = this.creditCardNo
      .replace(/\s/g, '')
      .toString()
      .substr(0, 6);
      this.paymentService.getCreditCardDetail('JPJSMN', test).subscribe(res => {
        if (!res) {
          return;
        }
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

using `(keyup)="onKey($event)"` to get value change, and do a validation on ts file based on response I get, however I notice if Im using  `(keyup)="onKey($event)"`, it doesnt detect copy and paste, and it keep requesting API,if there are better practice to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to create a custom 'digitOnly' Angular directive.

A great guide on how to do this can be found here:
https://codeburst.io/digit-only-directive-in-angular-3db8a94d80c3

The directive shown in the tutorial address issues such as copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the model updated when the user pasts something the same way as editing the value, you can just use

```
(ngModelChange)="pasteEvent($event)"

<div>
    <input
      (keypress)="numberOnly($event)"
      class="input"
      type="text"
      (ngModelChange)="pasteEventcreditCardNo(creditCardNo)"
      [(ngModel)]="creditCardNo"
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input
      class="input"
      type="text"
      (ngModelChange)="pasteEventcardHolderName(cardHolderName)"
      [(ngModel)]="cardHolderName"
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: is there any link where i can read more about this ? and how  it will be in ts file ?

Comment: I am updating the answer please check.